# Index out of range when navigating

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a tabbed page with a frame with tapped_gesture. I want to navigation to my other page the problem is when I tapped the frame I am getting a out of index exception error. Why am I getting this?

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>     at TBSApp.View.CAFPage.SetCAFNo () [0x00021] in C:\Users\Micromax\source\repos\lawrence317\TBSApp\TBSApp\TBSApp\View\CAFPage.xaml.cs:112 
>     at TBSApp.View.CAFPage.Initialize () [0x00016] in C:\Users\Micromax\source\repos\lawrence317\TBSApp\TBSApp\TBSApp\View\CAFPage.xaml.cs:39 
>     at TBSApp.View.CAFPage..ctor () [0x0000f] in C:\Users\Micromax\source\repos\lawrence317\TBSApp\TBSApp\TBSApp\View\CAFPage.xaml.cs:31 
>     at TBSApp.View.CAFMenuPage+d__2.MoveNext () [0x0002a] in C:\Users\Micromax\source\repos\lawrence317\TBSApp\TBSApp\TBSApp\View\CAFMenuPage.xaml.cs:25 }

I tried to enclose the navigation in a try catch statement

```
private async void CAF_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new CAFPage());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       await DisplayAlert("Navigation Error", ex.ToString(), "Ok");
   }
}
```

The code above shows when I tapped the frame it should navigate to my CAFPage but I am getting a exception error

Comment: Please post CAFPage code.

Comment: And also where you are assigning the initial NavigationPage